# Find the maximum volume of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

In order to inscribe a rectangle between the parabola $$ y=-x^2+2 $$and the x-axis so that the maximum cylinder volume is obtained by a complete rotation around the y-axis, I know that I should derivate the formula of the volume in order to find the maximum. However, I think I'm missing something since the result isn't what I expected (result: y=1).

Comment: You ask about *volume*, yet you say "the answer is"
 $\;y=1\;$ ...?

Comment: Yes, it might sound odd, but it does not ask for the maximum volume, but the maximum y of the rectangle so that I can get the maximum volume

Comment: If you showed how you got $y=1$ (without skipping any significant details), someone might see what you missed.

Comment: Oh, that's way another thing... Please edit your question to reflect this: you ask about the value of $\;y_1=\;$ the $\;y\,-$ ordinate so that the rectangle...etc....**and with oridnate** $\;y_1\;$ has maximal volume"...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Actually, y=1 should be the result of the problem, not the result I got.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of a cylinder is given by $V = r^{2}*h*pi$. In your situation $h=y$ and $r=x$. The problem at hand is:

$$ max \ f(x,y) = yx^{2}\pi \\ 
subject \ to: \ y=-x^{2} +2, \quad x \ge 0\\$$

Combine equality constraint with cost function: $f(y) = 2\pi y - y^{2}\pi $.
$ f'(y) = 2\pi - 2 \pi y$, equals zero if y = 1.